# Excel vba transfer column to another table

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet

Helo everyone,

i would like to transfer column A-K to another table starting at row number six.

it should transfer the columns, if i click a button. The Userform will open and ask me the referencenumber, which registered in Coumn A. All rows which include the chosen referencenumber  should transfer to another table.

My code does not work because it take all column. And it does not delete the rows from the copy area.

The destination area shoul be a archiv.

Thanks very much!

```
Sub Archiv()
  
Dim Zeile As Long
Dim ZeileMax As Long
Dim Bereich As Range

With Sheets("Protokoll")

    'Set Bereich = .Rows(3)
    
    ZeileMax = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    For Zeile = 6 To ZeileMax
    
    If .Cells(Zeile, 1).Value = Userform_boxnumber.Value Then
        'Set Bereich = Union(Bereich, .Rows(Zeile))
        
        'Range(Cells(ilastRow, 1), Cells(ilastRow, 11)).Select
        
    End If

Next Zeile

Bereich.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Archiv").Range("A3")

End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Union` to collect the matching rows is a good idea. One issue with `Union` is that none of the ranges are allowed to be `Nothing` or it causes an error. So the first row added to the range must be done without using `Union`. That is why I use an `If Else` Statement to handle the first matched row.

I use `.Resize` to trim the ranges from a full row into just columns A-K.

Finally, I use `.Delete` to clear the copy area before placing new data into "Archiv". You can also use `.ClearContents` or  `= ""`, all of those accomplish the same general goal.

```vb
Sub Archiv()
  
    Dim Zeile As Long
    Dim ZeileMax As Long
    Dim Bereich As Range
    
    With Sheets("Protokoll")
        
        ZeileMax = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        
        For Zeile = 6 To ZeileMax
            If .Cells(Zeile, 1).Value = Userform_boxnumber.Value Then
                If Bereich Is Nothing Then
                    Set Bereich = .Rows(Zeile).Resize(1, 11)
                Else
                    Set Bereich = Union(Bereich, .Rows(Zeile).Resize(1, 11))
                End If
            End If
        Next
        
    End With

    With Sheets("Archiv")
        'Clearing the Archiv Copy area
        ZeileMax = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If ZeileMax > 6 Then .Range(.Cells(6, 1), .Cells(ZeileMax, 11)).Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp

        If Not Bereich Is Nothing Then Bereich.Copy Destination:=.Range("A6")
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! If i use the code, i got the error message "Object or with block problems

Comment: @Green Which line causes the error?

Comment: @Green In my testing, I found that a possible source of errors could be that `.Cells(Zeile, 1).Value = Userform_boxnumber.Value` is never true and therefore `Bereich` is `Nothing` and cannot perform `.Copy` in the last line. Make sure that when you are evaluating the If Statement, that both values are the same type (String & String or Double & Double), this will at least ensure that you aren't skipping valid matches due to incorrect typing.